# Mysql multiple row count?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database full of rows like

```
id,action,date
2,2,2010-03-01
3,2,2010-03-01
4,3,2010-03-01
5,3,2010-03-01
6,4,2010-02-01
7,4,2010-02-01
```

And I want to select all the count all the 2's and all the 3's and all the 4's. But I don't want to have to do 3 different SELECT COUNT() commands, is there a way to do this in a single command?

Note, I want to display this as something like

- Action 2 = 2
- Action 3 = 2
- Action 4 = 2
- (etc etc).

And I will also need to specific a date (so it only counts all the 2,3,4,etc for dates between 2010-02-03 and 2010-03-01 for example)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   SELECT action
        , Count(*)
     FROM Table
    WHERE date BETWEEN startDate AND EndDate
 GROUP BY Action
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY action
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `GROUP BY action` your query. Also you could combine it with a `WHERE id IN (2,3,4)` to only get the rows for those ids.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM tableA GROUP BY columnA WHERE DATE BETWEEN dateFrom AND dateTO